# SQLAlchemy filter out lines that are not distinct across multiple columns

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Say I have data on a table as such:

```
id | other_id | category | amount
--------------------------------
1  | abc      | widget   | 100
2  | abc      | widget   | 200
3  | def      | widget   | 100
4  | ghi      | gadget   | 100
5  | ghi      | gadget   | 100
6  | jkl      | gadget   | 100
7  | jkl      | gadget   | 100
```

I want to query this table to return

```
(other_id, category, sum_of_amount)
```

where `sum_of_amount` is the sum of the `amount` column over the all rows in the same `other_id`. In addition to this, I want to exclude the tuples where the combination of `category` and `sum_of_amount` are NOT unique. So the query should return tuples:

```
(abc, widget, 300)
(def, widget, 100)
```

and not any of the `gadget` rows because the combination `(gadget, 200)` is not unique.

So far, I have this:

```
with session_scope() as db_session:
  query = db_session.query(
    ModelClass.other_id,
    ModelClass.category,
    label('sum_of_amount', func.sum(ModelClass.amount))
  ).group_by(
    ModelClass.other_id,
    ModelClass.category
  )
```

This query is not filtering anything out. I think I need to use distinct somehow but I can't figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the result set of `(ohter_id, category, sum_of_amount)` with the query as you noted::

```
=# SELECT other_id, category, SUM(amount) AS sum_of_amount
FROM test
GROUP BY other_id, category;

 other_id │ category │ sum_of_amount
──────────┼──────────┼───────────────
 abc      │ widget   │           300
 ghi      │ gadget   │           200
 jkl      │ gadget   │           200
 def      │ widget   │           100
(4 rows)
```

And then, you have to exclude rows whose `(category, sum_of_amount)` are not unique. In above result set to determine every rows' uniqueness, you can add new column containing the number of rows having same `(category, sum_of_amount)` like below:

```
=# SELECT other_id, category, SUM(amount) AS sum_of_amount,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category, SUM(amount)) AS duplicates
FROM test
GROUP BY other_id, category;

 other_id │ category │ sum_of_amount │ duplicates
──────────┼──────────┼───────────────┼───────
 ghi      │ gadget   │           200 │     2
 jkl      │ gadget   │           200 │     2
 def      │ widget   │           100 │     1
 abc      │ widget   │           300 │     1
(4 rows)
```

As you can see in above demonstration, you have determinants in the hands. Now you can generate the result set that you want to find by adding `WHERE` clause using the `duplicates` column. Since window functions(the `OVER` part of `duplicates` column) are not allowed in WHERE clauses and we have to evaluate the result of window function after sums of amounts have calculated, we have to use subquery.

```
=# SELECT other_id, category, sum_of_amount
FROM (
  SELECT other_id, category, SUM(amount) AS sum_of_amount,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category, SUM(amount)) AS duplicates
  FROM test
  GROUP BY other_id, category
) d
WHERE duplicates = 1
ORDER BY other_id, category;

 other_id │ category │ sum_of_amount
──────────┼──────────┼───────────────
 abc      │ widget   │           300
 def      │ widget   │           100
(2 rows)
```

SQLAlchemy query expression of above SQL could be:

```
from sqlalchemy import func, over
sum_of_amount = label('sum_of_amount', func.sum(ModelClass.amount))
duplicates = over(func.count('*'),
                  partition_by=(ModelClass.category, sum_of_amount))
query = db_session.query(
    ModelClass.other_id,
    ModelClass.category,
    sum_of_amount,
    duplicates,
  ).group_by(
    ModelClass.other_id,
    ModelClass.category
  ).from_self(
    ModelClass.other_id,
    ModelClass.category,
    sum_of_amount
  ).filter(duplicates == 1)
```

Comment: yoloseem, this doesn't quite seem to be working. If I leave out the .filter(duplicates == 1) I get the same result. I'm using Postgresql if that makes a difference.

Comment: yoloseem, the over() function doesn't seem to be working correctly as it's seems to be generating all duplicates values to 1. If I change the filter clause to filter(duplicates > 1), I get zero results back.

Comment: yoloseem, found the problem: in your over() function, it should be partition by ModelClass.category, sum_of_amount. That works, thanks!

Comment: @ericso Oh, I apologize for that wrong code. Actually I didn't test python code after converting SQL into SQLAlchemy query. Now I altered the answer.